# Avoiding the ecological fallacy

Tags: multilevel-analysis

My question is about how to handle misalignment between the levels of the data and outcome.

In this case suppose I have

1. Household income (Level 1)
2. County median housing value (Level 2)
3. County median household income (Level 2; aggregate of #1)

I am interested in estimating house value (Level 1) but I do not have direct measurements. As mentioned I do have the county median housing value and household income -- but I want to avoid making the ecological fallacy.

Given my data (or lack thereof) are there any methods to validly estimate the value for a given house? (even if the estimate is relatively wide)

So far the best I have come up with is to assume the value of a given house is equal to the county average plus/minus household income times some scale factor.